# Create video from base64 images taken in selenium

Tags: java, image, video, playframework, base64

I am taking screenshots in selenium headless and getting them as base64 images from the webdriver.
I want to convert my screenshot taken each 100ms to a video
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

if you have base 64, is so easy to rebuild de picture.

i think this can help you
https://www.ontestautomation.com/creating-a-video-capture-of-your-selenium-tests-using-monte-screen-recorder/